# Swift: Resize Embedded Custom NSView

Tags: macos, swift, nsview

I have a custom NSView that is embedded in a NSScrollView.

I have set the custom view to use a different view controller.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var clipView: NSClipView!
    var vc : NSViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        {
            vc = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("vc") as? NSViewController
            clipView.documentView = vc!.view
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to work, but I want the view controller in custom view to grow when I resize my outer window.

I have set constraints and the custom view grows accordingly, but the content says the same width.

[image]

When the window is expanded the custom frame changes size but its contents do not resize. For instance I'd like the button in this case to stay right aligned in the view.

[image]

As you can see the red background of the custom view changes size when the window expands, but the button remains in its original location.

How do I get the inner view to resize with the outer view?

UPDATE: Have followed the suggestions below. I've added an NSScrollView now and with all constraints it follows the resize beautifully. When I remove the bottom constraint it collapses in on itself and is bottom aligned:

[image]

I guess I need to specify a height and to top align the view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a background on the view itself, you can see that its size/position doesn't change.

```
vc.view.wantsLayer = true
vc.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

[image: example]

So you can add constraints telling it to fill the whole clip view:

```
vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// these are 10.11-only APIs, but you can use the visual format language or any other autolayout APIs
vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(vc.view.superview!.leadingAnchor).active = true
vc.view.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(vc.view.superview!.topAnchor).active = true
vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(vc.view.superview!.bottomAnchor).active = true
vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(vc.view.superview!.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

[image: fixed version]

But then I would ask, why are you using a scroll view at all?

Comment: That was an excellent answer to my question and was nearly just what I was looking for. You were right to ask about why I was using the scroll view. I actually have a few tables that I want to present vertically. I was trying to get the view to grow horizontally whilst keeping the vertical scroll. Using the code above obviously squishes all the view content into the screen. How can I retain the vertical height? Thanks

Comment: @iphaaw you should be able to simply omit the bottom constraint. The scroll/clip views are designed to cope with a document view that's larger than their bounds.

Comment: I have followed the suggestions below. I've added an NSScrollView now and with all constraints it follows the resize beautifully. When I remove the bottom constraint it collapses in on itself and is bottom aligned:

See updated question for picture. 
I guess I need to specify a height and to top align the view. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect you should be able to specify an align-top-to-superview constraint, and no bottom constraint. The view's automatic contentHugging constraints should make it grow to the necessary height, assuming its subviews are correctly constrained. (There may be some extra tricks involved because of the NSClipView.) But if you're just displaying data, why not use something that's designed for this, like NSTableView?

Comment: Thank you for you help. Your answer's were very good and you've certainly earned your bounty. I still have one last problem to go: I am using 3-4 NSTableViews each embedded in their own NSScrollView, which in turn are embedded in a master NSScrollView. The master NSScrollView is what I am trying to get to work above. They are collapsing on themselves so I think I only need to set the height of the TableView's NSScrollViews and I should be close.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Managed to fix my last problem with a 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'. Your code worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the right constrains in the button after the outer view constraints change you might want to call view.layoutIfNeeded() or button.layoutIfNeeded()